# Overload operator<< and >> in a c++ struct

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I have a class and a structure inside the class like that :

```
class MyClass : public QObject
{
public:
    ....

    struct MyStruct
    {
       quint8 val1;
    }
};
```

I would like to overload the operators << and >> for the struct, but I don't know how to do. For the moment, I do like that :

```
class MyClass : public QObject
{
public:
    ....

    struct MyStruct
    {
       quint8 val1;

       QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &out, const MyStruct& _myStruct)
       {
           out << _myStruct.val1;
           return out;
       }

       QDataStream &operator>>(QDataStream &in, MyStruct& _myStruct)
       {
           in >> _myStruct.val1;
           return in;
       }
    };
};
```

but it is not OK

Comment: [operator overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to declare the operators as `friend`:

```
       friend QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &out, const MyStruct& _myStruct)
       {
           out << _myStruct.val1;
           return out;
       }

       friend  QDataStream &operator>>(QDataStream &in, MyStruct& _myStruct)
       {
           in >> _myStruct.val1;
           return in;
       }
```

Comment: I try to declare the operators as friend ; it is OK for operator<< but I have this error for operator>> `erreur : no match for 'operator>>' in 'in >> _myStruct.val1'`

Comment: Sorry, it is OK, the solution needed to be cleaned

Answer (score 2):

Usually you specify those operators as *non-member functions* in the *same namespace* scope as the type they are trying to output. This is to allow for [argument-dependent-lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) upon use.

```
class MyClass { [...]
};

QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream& qstr, MyClass::Mystruct const& rhs) {
     [...]
    return qstr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think Adding `QDataStream` as your class member will be fine. In the context which you mean, `operator>>` only accept one parameter. Here is the code:

```
class MyClass : public QObject
{
private:
QDataStream in;
QDataStream out;
...

public:
    ....

    struct MyStruct
    {
       quint8 val1;

       QDataStream &operator<<(const MyStruct& _myStruct)
       {
           out << _myStruct.val1;
           return out;
       }

       QDataStream &operator>>(MyStruct& _myStruct)
       {
           in >> _myStruct.val1;
           return in;
       }
    };
};
```

Comment: I expect the OP wanted to say `someQDataStream << MyStructObj;`.

Comment: @chris It is OK. I get what you mean. You mean overload operator<< without inheritance of QDataStream class and parameter passing. The answer that declare the operators as friend is suitable for your question.